# No '\docs' folder was found to build GitHub Pages message

Tags: github

I'm new here.
I'm learning Git and Github and here's my first question : I got this message in my e-mails because in my settings on Github I've chosen for the source branch:main and folder: /docs

> The page build failed for the `main` branch with the following error:
>
> No `/docs` folder was found to build GitHub Pages. Check the source
> setting for this repository. For more information, see
> https://docs.github.com/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#missing-docs-folder.

My question is why do i have this message ? I know that I have to create a docs folder or chose root folder but where do I have to create it (if I have to)? And do I have to create it ?
Sorry, it's maybe a noob question ... I just want to understand why.

I resolved this problem by choosing folder /root but I just want to understand...

Can you help me please ? ^^

Comment: GitHub Pages are strictly a GitHub feature. I snipped the [tag:git] tag. For most basic GitHub questions, search the documentation that GItHub provide; it's usually not bad.